Implementing Lin-Kernighan algorithm for TSP
I'm looking for some guidance in implementing the Lin-Kernighan heuristic for the TSP. I have been trying on and off for a couple of weeks and I have read a bunch of papers, two of the better ones I have found is this one (pages 39-44) and this one (especially page 12), but I have been unsuccessful and I feel as if I still do not have a proper understanding of how the algorithm actually works.
Perhaps this is just the nature of the algorithm but every description I have read is very convoluted and hard to understand. From what I have gathered the general idea is to implement a k-opt algorithm (as opposed to 2 or 3-opt, both of which I have implemented) but what I can't seem to figure out is how to implement it in practice. Every attempt I have made has ended up being worse than 3-opt.
I guess I am wondering if anyone is aware of any resources which explain the algorithm in a clear and succinct manner. Perhaps some pseudo-code (there is some in the second paper I linked but it is written in a very strange way with a bunch of go-to statements) or a lecture explaining it, or if anyone has any general advice.
I am writing the problem for a college assignment (don't worry, we're allowed to use online resources!) and my best attempt so far consists of Christofides algorithm and the 3-opt heuristic.
